# Prefix to Infix?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, prefix, infix-notation

In my class one of our assignments is to convert a prefix equation to infix. After reading that section I still have no idea what I'm doing. The book had some code that will solve a prefix equation when given but I have no idea how it does it or how I would display the infix version. Any help would be appreciated in explaining how this code finds the solution and how I could have it display a infix version.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int prefixExpr(istream &exprStream);

int main() {
string input;
cout << "Enter prefix expressions to evaluate. \nPress enter after each expression, and press enter on a blank line  to quit." << endl;
cout << "Enter a prefix expression to evaluate: ";
getline(cin, input);
while (input.size() != 0){
    istringstream exprStream(input);
    cout << prefixExpr(exprStream) << endl;
    cout << "Enter a prefix expression to evaluate: ";
    getline(cin, input);
}
return 0;
}

int prefixExpr(istream &exprStream) {
char ch = exprStream.peek();
while (isspace(ch)) {
    ch = exprStream.get();
    ch = exprStream.peek();
}
cout << ch << endl;

if (isdigit(ch)) {
    int number;
    exprStream >> number;

    cout << number << endl;

    return number;
}
else {
    ch = exprStream.get();

    int value1 = prefixExpr(exprStream);
    int value2 = prefixExpr(exprStream);

    switch (ch) {
    case '+': return value1 + value2;
    case '-': return value1 - value2;
    case '*': return value1 * value2;
    case '/': return value1 / value2;
    default: cout << "Bad input expression";
        exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I try not to give out a full answer on homework questions because otherwise you wouldn't learn anything. So, please try to break what problem(s) you're having down into small individual pieces. Try to understand what prefix and infix expressions look like and how they're supposed to be parsed (by a human). Then think about how you can translate those rules into code. When you have an issue with a specific part, try to debug it with your debugger. If you still cannot solve it, then come to StackOverflow and describe exactly what's wrong and include a minimal example that reproduces your issue

Comment: I think I understand how you convert it but I have no clue on how to put that into code. The reason why I included the code in my post was to hopefully have someone explain it and for me to understand how I could write my code for the assignment. At this point I'm completely stuck as I have no idea how to convert between the two with code.

Comment: Pick a minimal example, like `+*321` or even `*32` and go through the code by hand.